# button not appearing in IE7

Tags: jquery, css, button, dialog

Using jquery, I build a dialog box with cancel & ok buttons which appears properly in IE 8 & Firefox & others but not in IE7. Even in IE7 if I disable & then enable some property of that input-type-button element, the button starts appearing.

What might be the causes ? Any similar experiences ?

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing the code you're working with. Best to post a fiddle or link to your web page.

Comment: 1. go to http://fe.avvio.com/convert/site/Kellys%20Resort%20Hotel/en/mda.php?checkin=2012-08-24&nights=3
2. Click on "Booking Request Form" below the top navigation menu
3. Select Checkin date : 26 August & then Submit
4. You will see a dialog box which I'm talking about.

Comment: search for div with id avail-present

Comment: Did my previous comment make any sense ? Did anybody tried that problem ? TIA